# ionic scrollable tab with fixed position and scrollable content

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I used  [plugins for tabbed slidebox.](https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox)

Since my contents inside slidebox is large, it needs scrolling. So for that purpose, I changed `tabSlideBox.css`.
I made the height auto so that I can see all the content inside the slidebox.
But it made the whole tab and slidebox scrollable. I want the tab fixed and content inside the slidebox scrollable. I didn't find any method for that.
I can provide the code if necessary. 
Thank you in advance.

```
.tabbed-slidebox .slider {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my app, I just always put all the content into the ion-content element. When the content became bigger then the screen, it would become scrollable automatically.

Comment: I can't split tabs and slidebox since i have used plugins for tabbed slidebox. So i have put both inside the ion-content. But i need my scrollable tabs fixed.